# Spring:configuration xml not found in classpath

Tags: spring, classpath, filenotfoundexception, applicationcontext

For my simple maven project this doesn't work:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
```

`config.xml` is resided at the same class level

How,actually,add config.xml to classpath?
**note:** my project is a lib,if I do the same in other web project with configuration in 
web.xml:

```
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath*:config.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
```

that it works OK

Here I needn't web.xml, just correct classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enter `classpath*:config.xml`, the `classpath*` is a wild card indicates that you want to load every file matching `config.xml` on the entire classpath, not just the single file `config.xml`. This may be why your solution is working otherwise.

When instantiating a new `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`, try giving the full classpath as an argument: `com\sergionni\myproj\config.xml`.

Comment: You can try that same prefix if that's what you need.


ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:config.xml");

Answer (score 0):

If your config xml is in package com.anywhere.here then try this:

```
ApplicationContext myAppContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/anywhere/here/config.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of maven project, right click on project-maven-update project, this helped me solve my issue.

Answer (score -2):

Please do This code - it worked

AbstractApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");

o/w: Delete main method class and recreate it while recreating please uncheck Inherited abstract method its worked